# Value of this in object's method defined with anonymous function literal

Tags: javascript, node.js, methods, this, anonymous

The following object `myObj` has the same method defined in three different ways (at least I though they were interchangeable), but the method defined with anonymous literal behaves differently:

```
const myObj = {
  msg: 'dude',
  say1: () => {
    console.log(this.msg)
  },
  say2: function() {
    console.log(this.msg)
  },
  say3() {
    console.log(this.msg)
  }
}

myObj.say1()
myObj.say2()
myObj.say3()
```

Result:

```
undefined
dude
dude
```

Where does `this` point to from inside `say1` ? Why is it different from `say2` and `say3` ? I am running this in Node.js (v8.4.0).

Comment: Arrow functions automatically bind `this`. So `this` is equal to whatever this was equal to in the surrounding function.

Comment: You have an arrow function, a regular function, and a method definition. The value of `this` is different in different types of functions, as arrow functions use the `this` value from the surrounding scope.

Comment: Thanks, couldn't find the question that would answer this. I completely forgot the phrase "arrow function", that would have made it.